# How do you handle singular/plural for mathematical expressions that evaluate to 1?

Tags: grammatical-number

I know that it is correct to say

> There is 1 composition of *n*.

but what if instead of "1", I use an expression that evaluates to 1? For example, what is the grammatical number in these sentences?

> There is/are **2<sup>0</sup>** composition(s) of *n*. *(two to the zero)*
>
> There is/are **3 - 2** composition(s) of *n*. *(three minus two)*
>
> There is/are **2<sup>0</sup>=1** composition(s) of *n*. *(two to the zero, which equals one)*
>
> There is/are **1=2<sup>0</sup>** composition(s) of *n*. *(one, which equals two to the zero)*

This problem comes up somewhat frequently for me when describing the base case in a [proof by induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general pattern is:

1. If the phrase does not end in "1", use plural: "There are 1=2^0 compositions of n."
2. If the phrase does not *equal* "1", use plural: "There are 2^1 compositions of n."
3. Otherwise, use singular: "There is 2^0=1 composition of n."

I do not have a link to any particular style guide on this and am going entirely by ear. I suspect the primary debate would revolve around (1) but only because the phrase also *starts* with "1". The following sounds completely incorrect to my ear:

> INCORRECT — There is 2^0 composition of n.

Answer (score 0):

If the result does not trivially evaluate to 1 then use plural, which is proper for unknown numbers of items.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you convert these problems to word problems you will find your verb agrees with your noun for each part of the equation.
There are 2 items which are powered to the zero, so 1 item results.
There are 3 items and 2 are removed, so 1 item remains.
1 is the result when 2 items are powered to the zero.

However, if you are referencing the number as the subject, a number is singular no matter its value and the verb should reflect that.
When 1256 is powered to the zero, 1 is still the result.